# How to go to next record in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am new in MS access 2007 programming..
I want to get information from database one by one.But the code which i am using is not executing that. If I am on first record then it directly goes to last record which i dont want. I want to take it to the next record..
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub MoveNextBttn_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM Table_Emp_Info"
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(str)
    Dim xxx As Integer
    xxx = 1

    'If the recordset is empty, exit.
    If rst.EOF Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Do Until rst.EOF
        Emp_ID_Text.Value = rst.Fields("EmpID")
        Rowsource_Designation.Value = rst.Fields("Designation")
        RowSource_Dept.Value = rst.Fields("Dept")
        DOJ_Text.Value = rst.Fields("Date_Of_Joining")
        rst.MoveNext
         'xxx = xxx + 1
    Loop

    rst.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a **bound** form instead of an **unbound** form.

It sounds like you are trying to reinvent functionality that is built into Access.  To change your form from an unbound form to a bound form do the following:

1. Open the form in design view.
2. Press F4 to bring up the form property sheet.
3. Click on the Data tab.
4. Enter `SELECT * FROM Table_Emp_Info` in the RecordSource property (you could also simply enter `Table_Emp_Info` to bind the form directly to the query's underlying table).
5. Click on the Format tab and make sure that Navigation Buttons is set to Yes (the default).
6. Get rid of all that unnecessary code you wrote.

Now you can simply use the 5 buttons at the bottom left of your form to navigate your records.  From left to right the buttons will take you to the First, Previous, Next, Last, or New record.

For more information search on "ms access bound form".

Comment: **Need** to use a bound form? No, not really. It's *better* to do so in Access, most of the time, but something like Anders Lindahl's answer would work also.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok, but you are writing the values from `Table_Emp_Info` to the same locations in every iteration:

```
    Emp_ID_Text.Value = rst.Fields("EmpID")
    Rowsource_Designation.Value = rst.Fields("Designation")
    RowSource_Dept.Value = rst.Fields("Dept")
    DOJ_Text.Value = rst.Fields("Date_Of_Joining")
    rst.MoveNext
```

This makes the locations holding the values of the last row at the end of the loop. Was this your intention, or did you want something different?

*Edit*

Judging by your comment, you want to step through the tuples of `Table_Emp_Info`. In that case, you do not want the loop - the click should do the `rst.MoveNext` and update the fields where the data is displayed.

Something like this could work, but a disclaimer is in place: I know close to nothing about how the Access model works.

```
private rst As Recordset

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table_Emp_Info")
    call UpdateForm()
End Sub

private sub UpdateForm()
    if not rst.EOF
        Emp_ID_Text.Value = rst.Fields("EmpID")
        Rowsource_Designation.Value = rst.Fields("Designation")
        RowSource_Dept.Value = rst.Fields("Dept")
        DOJ_Text.Value = rst.Fields("Date_Of_Joining")
    end if
end sub

private sub MoveNextBttn_Click()
    if not rst.EOF then
        rst.MoveNext
        call UpdateForm()
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for showing concern.. I want to navigate through each record after clicking button each time..Data is displaying on form containing textbox and combox for each field

Answer (score 0):

```
Do while not rst.EOF
        Emp_ID_Text.Value = rst.Fields("EmpID")
        Rowsource_Designation.Value = rst.Fields("Designation")
        RowSource_Dept.Value = rst.Fields("Dept")
        DOJ_Text.Value = rst.Fields("Date_Of_Joining")
        rst.MoveNext
         'xxx = xxx + 1
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you should be using a single SQL UPDATE statement to do the update, instead of walking through a form and a recordset and copying the data record-by-record.

However, you don't give enough information for me to provide sample SQL, since there's no way for me to know how your destination form relates to your source data.

It could be that you're creating new records and copying the data in from the recordset, in which case you'd use a SQL INSERT statement instead of an UPDATE, but there just isn't enough information to go on here.

ASIDE:

By the way,  as a guard clause to prohibit executing the loop when the recordset returns nothing, the usual method in DAO is to check if the recordset's .Recordcount propert is 0:

```
  'If the recordset is empty, skip the loop.
  If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
     Do Until rst.EOF
       Emp_ID_Text.Value = rst.Fields("EmpID")
       Rowsource_Designation.Value = rst.Fields("Designation")
       RowSource_Dept.Value = rst.Fields("Dept")
       DOJ_Text.Value = rst.Fields("Date_Of_Joining")
       rst.MoveNext
       'xxx = xxx + 1
     Loop
  End If
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing ' you omitted this step
```

You actually don't want to EXIT, because you haven't closed your recordset if you do.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this before your do loop:

```
rst.movelast

rst.movefirst
```